# Foundation Top-bar radius

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to round the top-bar navigation from foundation zurb, I managed to make the left side rounded but not the right side. I only need to round the top part of the navigation.

this made the left side rounded but when I put the right side it didn't change at all.

```
.top-bar.radius {
        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: There's not gonna be that much and you won't see the proper style of the nav http://jsfiddle.net/6tLz2vzh/

Comment: You need to link in the CSS...can't help otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've included in your fiddle the foundation css files as external. Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g03fd8c9/2/). 
`border-radius-top-right: 3px;` is properly displayed. Look if some of default foundation classes overwrites your style.

Comment: Thanks for including it. I don't see the right being rounded though. I tried to put overflow:hidden that sorted out the top right but it might be wrong or something.

Comment: The only rounded side is the top left corner really. Need the top right corner as well to be rounded.

Comment: [Fiddle with bigger radius](http://jsfiddle.net/g03fd8c9/3/)
Somebody else see the `border-radius` at both top corners?

Comment: Unless chrome is messing up or something :/

Comment: That's weird i don't see it on my chrome :/. Okay not showing on my end though :/ this is definitely weird.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have a specificity conflict. For debugging, try to add `!important` to the end of the CSS propriety.

If it works, then a solution is to create a class for this bar, to increase its specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Your style may gets rejected by the Foundation CSS.

Try adding it in the **style** attribute:

> style="border-top-left-radius: 3px;"